# CSS Sourcemaps not generating properly with gulp, SASS, & autoprefixer

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

I have the following gulp task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.src('html/css/sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
        style: 'compressed',
        loadPath: 'plugin/css/sass',
        sourcemap: true,
        sourcemapPath: '/css/sass',
        container : 'local_sass'
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('html/css'));
```

The problem I'm having is the SASS compiler is properly generating the sourcemaps and adding the sourcemap comment, but then autoprefixer removes the comment (and I don't think it's updating the sourcemaps either).

I've tried removing autoprefixer and it works perfectly, but when I put it back in, they comment is removed. I also tried adding `{ map: true }`, but then each sourcemap just has the name `to.css.map`. I also tried adding `from` and `to` but I don't know how to do tell it current filename so it always writes to the same filename.

How would I go about getting autoprefixer to co-operate and **update the sourcemaps**? Is there another plugin I need to use?

Packages:

```
"gulp": "~3.8.6",
"gulp-autoprefixer": "~0.0.8",
"gulp-ruby-sass": "~0.7.0",
```

Comment: The `README.md` of `autoprefixer` says it can [handle sourcemaps](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer#source-map). It's probably using [postcss](https://github.com/postcss/postcss#source-map-1) for this.

Comment: The problem is it seems to remove them or not update them correctly.

Comment: I ran into the same issue. I created a GitHub issue for this: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-autoprefixer/issues/1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [gulp-sourcemaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps) if you switch to `gulp-sass`. Both `gulp-sass` and `gulp-autoprefixer` support gulp sourcemaps.

Implementation would look something like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpSass = require('gulp-sass');
var gulpAutoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('javascript', function() {
  gulp.src('src/**/*.scss')
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(gulpSass())
  .pipe(gulpAutoprefixer())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Which would write .map files in a maps directory.

**Note**: All manipulations from source .scss to target .css must be in the stream between `sourcemaps.init()` and `sourcemaps.write()`. This includes any minification such as `gulp-uglify`, which also [supports](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps/wiki/Plugins-with-gulp-sourcemaps-support) `gulp-sourcemaps`.

Comment: Thanks for documenting that. It looks like autoprefixer and SASS now both fully support sourcemaps so everything works as it should!

Comment: @linuxdan - You just saved me from having to crank open a bottle of whiskey on a Monday morning. I've been trying to narrow down why comment blocks being included/excluded would result in completely broken mapping/correct mapping. Answer === appending a legal header comment block "must be in the stream between sourcemaps.init() and sourcemaps.write()"

Answer (score 0):

I've created a small gulp plugin to [enable source map support for autoprefixer with gulp](https://gist.github.com/McNull/1331b911736c90dbae06):

```
var through = require('through2');
var prefix = require('autoprefixer');
var applySourceMap = require('vinyl-sourcemaps-apply');

module.exports = function(browsers, options) {

  options = options || {};

  return through.obj(function(file, enc, cb) {

    if(file.isStream()) {
      throw new Error('Streams not supported');
    }

    if(!file.isNull()) {

      if(file.sourceMap) {
        options.map = {
          annotation: false
        };
        options.to = options.from = file.relative;
      }

      var contents = file.contents.toString();

      var result = prefix(browsers).process(contents, options);
      contents = result.css;

      file.contents = new Buffer(contents);

      if(file.sourceMap) {
        applySourceMap(file, result.map.toString());
      }
    }

    this.push(file);
    cb();

  });

};
```

It's making use of [gulp-sourcemaps](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps), so any gulp plugin that support `gulp-sourcemaps` can be used in the stream pipeline:

```
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var concat = require('gulp-concat'); // Supports gulp-sourcemaps
var prefixer = require('./gulp-autoprefixer-map.js');

gulp.task('css', [], function() {
  gulp.src('src/**/*.css')
   .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
   .pipe(concat('app.css'))
   .pipe(prefixer())
   .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/'))
});
```

Unfortunately there's no support yet for SASS yet, but maybe someone can use the above to hack a plugin together and update this answer.

Comment: This would be close, but the concatenation is done by SASS (because it uses @import statements).